# How to allow current user to delete owned tags with acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

In my rails app I have an item page that lists tags for an item.  Users are able to add tags to items.  I want the current user to be able to remove tags, but only for tags that were added to that specific item by the current user.  I want to do this through ajax.  My code to make the tag list for the view looks like this:

```
<div id="tags">Tags: 
  <% @item.all_tags_list.each do |t| %>
    <span class="tag-container">
      <%= link_to t, tag_path(t) %>
      <% if @item.tags_from(current_user).include?(t) %>
        <span>
          <%= link_to "×", '#' %>
        </span>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The generated line looks something like: `Tags: tag1 tag2 tag3 x`.  In this case only tag3 was added to the current item page by the current user.  I want the current user to be able to click the x and remove tag3 from the item.  If tag2 was also added by the current user it would look like this `Tags: tag1 tag2 x tag3 x`.

How do I setup the route and method for the items_controller to accomplish this?  I believe it would end up being something like:

```
def remove_tag
  @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:id])
  tag = ????????
  @item.all_tags_list.remove(tag)
  @item.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

but how do I tell the controller which tag I want to remove when clicking the x, and how would I create the route.  There will likely be several tags with an x next to them on a given page.

Comment: Not your full answer but if you want the current_user to only delete his tags something like this: `tag = current_user.tags.find(params[:id])` so basically you need to scope it to only the current users tags.

Comment: I dont think this is correct.  I want to delete tags on the item that are owned by the current user.  Your line of code would find tags on the user which in my case there aren't any.

Comment: Concept is the same. Then scope the `current_user.items.find(...)` part.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused as to what you mean by "scope it to current users"

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like devise for authentication you have a `current_user` method in your controller which points to the actual logged in user model.

Then if you have associations like these:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
 end

 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags
 end
```

You can use these associations to look for tags which are belonging to items the `current_user` created.

Like:

```
 def show
   @item = current_user.items.find(params[item:id])
   @tag = item.tags.find(params[:id])
 end
```

routes:

```
 resources :items do
   resources :tags
 end
```

This is only for example.

Comment: I still need a way to target the specific tag to be deleted.  A user may have several owned tags for a given item.  Current user should be able to see all tags on an item but only able to delete the tags owned by current user.  I don't understand the routes code that you posted.